# Why should expand context for sibling selectors in Sizzle.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

I am reading the code of [Sizzle.js](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js) now and get confused by the following:

`newContext = rsibling.test( selector ) && testContext( context.parentNode ) || context;`

in line 301.

This part fixes the qSA method looking outside Element context. but I do not understand why we should make newContext context.parentNode instead of context when it comes to sibling.

I got nothing useful after google it. Maybe I use wrong keywords.

```js
Sizzle = $.find;
div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
alert(Sizzle('p+span',div));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p></p>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

I tested it above and it gets right answer.So I do not know why bother to use parentNode.

Can anyone explain it for me?
Thanks a lot. :)